# Android Studio music background

Tags: android

I want to play music in the background. I would like to change the song (there will be 2 songs) in my app. I successfully played a single song but I don't know how to add the second song.

I did it with Music Service:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private int length = 0;

public MusicService() {
}

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    MusicService getService() {
        return MusicService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.classic);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.setVolume(50, 50);
    }


    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int
                extra) {

            onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void pauseMusic() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }
}

public void resumeMusic() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}

public void startMusicClassic() {
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.classic);
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.setVolume(50, 50);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

}

public void stopMusic() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
        } finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
        } finally {
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And in Main I created a Button and wrote this code:

```
      //added button for first song
    Button classic_music_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_classicmusic);
    classic_music_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            playClassic();
        }
    });

}

void playClassic() {
    doBindService();
    Intent music = new Intent();
    music.setClass(this, MusicService.class);
    startService(music);
}

void doBindService() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class),
            Scon, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}


private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicService mServ;
private ServiceConnection Scon = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder
            binder) {
        mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder) binder).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServ = null;
    }
};
```

So for a second button that i will create what should I do to play a second song correctly?
Should I add a similar Class as MusicService for example? O r should I use MusicServiceForSecondButton and init everything as i did with first button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a broadcast receiver to start the service and check if any service is running or not before playing any song. In case of playing musing try to use foreground service.